# Practice in Amsterdam regarding Chalav stam

Tags: halacha, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

The Pri Chadash 115:6 writes that one can drink milk that was not watched by a Yisroel in an instance where there are no non-kosher animals, or if the non-kosher milk would be more expensive.

He writes towards the end that this is the minhag of Amsterdam.

Text:

הכלל העולה דבעיר שלא נמצא שם חלב טמא או שהיא יותר ביוקר מחלב טהור מותר לקנות מהעכו"ם חלב שחלבו בלא ראיית ישראל כלל וכן מצאתי המנהג פשוט פה אמסטרדם וכן נהגתי אני...‏

Is this recorded minhag of Amsterdam, is it still a minhag there or have the circumstances changed there?

Comment: I was under the impression that most of the Western European Jewish communities became secular in the 1800s, and were then flooded by eastern European Jews, then were killed in the Holocaust, and then were _again_ flooded with eastern European and north African Jews.

Comment: I believe in the Sdei Chemed, he quotes this Pri Chadash, and also mentions that this was not only the Minhag of Amsterdam, but also of Jews inArabic countries (as Muslims find pigs reprehensible)

Comment: http://www.vosizneias.com/99090/2012/01/18/netherlands-amsterdam-chief-rabbi-suspended-for-gay-stance/ FWIW

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv I thought the issue was Camel milk, not pig milk (which is green anyways).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't have it with me, but from what I remember the issue was pig milk, thus he states explicitly that in Arab countries it would be muttar

Comment: Seems important to quote the rest of the text, where he notes that, unlike the Pri Chadash himself, there were some people who were strict
וכן מצאתי המנהג פשוט פה אמשטירדאם וכן נהגתי אני ג"כ זולת קצת יחידים הנזהרים בזה.

Comment: @guest10236 There's always someone who will be strict about anything. Not that important to note.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is important to note because 1) the answers below indicate a different minhag than the Pri Chadash, and 2) it is (to me) amusing that the Pri Chadash did not consider himself strict in this regard

Comment: @guest10236 Are you suggesting that it was those Yechidim who won out and influenced the current practice? That's absurd. He wrote that 300 years ago. It's far more likely that something else caused the change.

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you always read everyone so uncharitably? I was suggesting that even early on, there was variation of practice, later as well. These things tend to ebb and flow over time.  Pointing out that the questioner's original source indicated this very variation is not unreasonable. I can't fathom how this incensed you.

Answer (score 1):

[Rav Yochanan of Holleschau](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8715-johanan-ben-isaac-of-holleschau) claims (recorded [here](https://app.pelorous.com/media_manager/public/76/Early%20Years%20of%20London%20-%20You%20and%20US.pdf), p. 30) that this was not the Minhag in Amsterdam, even at the time of the Peri Chadash.

See also [here](http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/129_69_74.pdf) (p. 32) where Rav Yitzchak Yosef quotes Sedei Chemed saying that the Minhag in Amsterdam is to prohibit unsupervised milk.

See [this website](http://www.nik.nl/2017/09/melk-en-zuivelproducten/) about milk products in Amsterdam now.

It starts with a statement:

> If there is no milk under rabbinical supervision available, then you are forced to buy products without supervision. 
>   All products in this section that contain E-120, cochineal, or carmine dye (carmine, karmic acid) are not allowed.

It then has a long list of products that are allowed and those that are non-kosher.